# C# Issues Getting LINQ Query Results - Query runs in LINQpad but not in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I'm trying to populate a `DataGridView` with the results from the below LINQ Query however for some reason I am betting the error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is the query:

```
var QueryAverageTime = 
  from so in tpDB.tblServiceOrders
  join sologs in tpDB.tblSOLogs on so.SONumber equals sologs.SONumber

  where so.DateClosed >= new DateTime(2014, 01, 13)
  where so.DateClosed <= new DateTime(2014, 01, 17)
  where sologs.ElapsedHours != 0 || sologs.ElapsedMinutes != 0

  group new { sologs.ElapsedHours, sologs.ElapsedMinutes } by sologs.SONumber into g
  group new { hours = g.Sum(x => x.ElapsedHours), mins = g.Sum(x => x.ElapsedMinutes) } by "Totals" into t

  select new
  {
     Average = t.Average(x => (x.hours * 60) + x.mins),
     Count = t.Count()
  };
dgvTimeSLAAverage.DataSource = QueryAverageTime.ToList();
```

==EDIT==
I'm not sure why this query has issues running when it works okay in LINQpad and returns results.

I have tried changing the

```
dgvTimeSLAAverage.DataSource = QueryAverageTime.ToList();
```

to

```
var test = QueryAverageTime.ToList();
```

however is still crashed at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.

The query runs okay when I remove the `Group By`

```
group new { hours = g.Sum(x => x.ElapsedHours), mins = g.Sum(x => x.ElapsedMinutes) } by "Totals" into t
```

This is the exception thrown:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.NominalTypeEliminator.VisitPropertyOp(Op op, Node n, PropertyRef propertyRef, Boolean throwIfMissing)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.NominalTypeEliminator.Visit(PropertyOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.PropertyOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitScalarOpDefault(ScalarOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(AggregateOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.AggregateOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitAncillaryOpDefault(AncillaryOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(VarDefOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.VarDefOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.NominalTypeEliminator.Visit(VarDefListOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.VarDefListOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.NominalTypeEliminator.Visit(GroupByIntoOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.GroupByIntoOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.NominalTypeEliminator.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.NominalTypeEliminator.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitApplyOp(ApplyBaseOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(OuterApplyOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.OuterApplyOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitApplyOp(ApplyBaseOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(OuterApplyOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.OuterApplyOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.NominalTypeEliminator.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitChildren(Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.NominalTypeEliminator.Visit(PhysicalProjectOp op, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.NominalTypeEliminator.Process()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.NominalTypeEliminator.Process(PlanCompiler compilerState, StructuredTypeInfo structuredTypeInfo, Dictionary`2 tvfResultKeys)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(DbCommandTree ctree, List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver, BridgeDataReaderFactory bridgeDataReaderFactory, ColumnMapFactory columnMapFactory)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext, IDbDependencyResolver resolver)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityProviderServices.CreateDbCommandDefinition(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderServices.CreateCommandDefinition(DbCommandTree commandTree, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.CreateCommandDefinition(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlanFactory.Prepare(ObjectContext context, DbQueryCommandTree tree, Type elementType, MergeOption mergeOption, Boolean streaming, Span span, IEnumerable`1 compiledQueryParameters, AliasGenerator aliasGenerator)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__a()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()
at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at TigerClaw.frmQuery.btnTimePerTicketQuery_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\dev\TigerClaw\TigerClaw\frmQuery.cs:line 1866
```

Comment: Which object is `null`?

Comment: I should mention that other basic queries run okay on the same database and the query returns results in LINQpad.

Comment: Hi David,
It breaks on the line:
dgvTimeSLAAverage.DataSource = QueryAverageTime.ToList();
The query does have results when run in LINQpad though. It only seems to start having trouble when I add the "group new { hours = g.Sum(x => x.ElapsedHours), mins = g.Sum(x => x.ElapsedMinutes) } by "Totals" into t" in the query

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.  Which *actual object* is `null`?  Don't guess, debug and find out.  For example, if `dgvTimeSLAAverage` is `null` then this has nothing to do with your query, you're simply not instantiating your `DataGridView`.

Comment: Hi David,
I'm not sure how to check sorry. :(
I have run other queries and populated the `DataGridView` okay. It's just this one query that seems to have issues.

Comment: This is a good opportunity to use a debugger, which will be an *extremely* valuable tool in your software development endeavors.  Assuming you're using Visual Studio, place a debugging breakpoint in this code and step through line-by-line as it executes.  You can examine the state of the objects at runtime, looking for anything which doesn't behave as expected.

Comment: It is crashing when doing the QueryAverageTime.ToList();
 It even crashed when doing var test = QueryAverageTime.ToList();

Comment: The stack trace in the exception will also contain useful information about the exception, such as the specific method which threw the exception.  You may also break the query into multiple steps to further isolate the problem.  I'm not trying to be abrupt here, but you need to examine the runtime behavior of the code in order to determine the problem.  "It doesn't work" and "it crashes" isn't a meaningful description of the problem and nobody here can debug it for you.

Comment: Thanks David,

The query stops working with the line:
group new { hours = g.Sum(x => x.ElapsedHours), mins = g.Sum(x => x.ElapsedMinutes) } by "Totals" into t" which is where is grouping by the sum of a group by. I thought this may be a common issue which somebody could identify. I've added some more details. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting that you're grouping on an aggregate. I have a feeling that it's working in LINQPad because it's using LinqToSQL whereas Visual Studio is using LinqToEF. LinqToEF may not have an appropriate translation yet, which might be the problem. This is my best guess anyway.

Comment: I did end up running this with `Linq-to-SQL` and it works fine.
Thanks for the tip. :-)